# How strong is Alexa NLP?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have below utterances in my intent.

What is the parameter value for today ?

What's the parameter value for today ?

What is a parameter value ?

Whats a parameter value ?

Now, if I ask alexa "what was my parameter value for today ?", It cant understand.

So, I wonder do I need to add all possible utterances with all tense, verbs, phrases, articles in mind ?

Comment: What were the utterances in other intents? Can you share your interaction model?

Comment: It is the only intent with above utterances present in my model.

Answer (score 0):

Alexa's NLP is very good. From my experience, I can say that it's constantly improving. The utterances you mentioned above can be minimized to just one or two. Ideally, you should give some 10 to 15 variants or more which covers the specified user intention and not duplicates of the same utterances.

Anyway, I tried your utterances as it is and got the intent recognized.